# row-span in doesn't work in tailwind with multiple images

Tags: css-grid, tailwind-css

im trying to creat a css grid  layout with multiple images using tailwind but im stuck because when i'm trying to span the rows it doesn't work, basicly i want the images to go down to the row-4 but theye stay at row-2
this is my reference: [this is the layout im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF6ez.png)

this is my result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oidUt.png)

my code:

```
<div class="container grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-4 gap-4 p-4">

<img src="/img/h1.jpg" class="col-span-2" alt="">
<img src="/img/v1.jpg" class="row-span-4 " alt="">
<img src="/img/v2.jpg" class="row-span-4" alt="">
<img src="/img/h2.jpg" class="col-span-2"alt="">

</div>
```

Comment: please any helppppppppppppp

Comment: There is no need to yell...

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I think you need to change.

The first is the size of the grid: the grid in your example does not have 4 rows, but only two. You need to change the row and col span accordingly.

The second is the use of images in the grid. If you use images, it seems they need to have the exact correct aspect ratio for the grid, otherwise they will not align. Therefore I suggest you use divs.

You can [see a working example here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WRfExwJwjR). I also included the not correct working version with images in it.

Simplified version of the code:

```
<div class="w-5/6 h-64 grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-2 gap-4">
    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-1 rounded-lg bg-cover bg-[url(...)]">1</div>
    <div class="row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-cover bg-[url(...)]">2</div>
    <div class="row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-cover bg-[url(...)]">3</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-1 rounded-lg bg-cover bg-[url(...)]">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i got you but im really despointed how tailwind can not hundle multiple images..., one last question if i want to use a local image inside a div not an external url how can i do that ? i tried bg-[/images/] to acces them but doesn't work or it's impossible maybe ,

Comment: You should use url also for internal images, like `bg-[url(/img/image.jpg)]`.

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work it seems that with the url you can only add links.... so i have to add img to have the src like this i'll have my local images...

Comment: O, I see. I think you need quotes around the file name. See docs here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values